# Unable to use a NuGet package after adding it to my project

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

New .net developer here. I can usually use a library by adding it to my project with "dotnet add [PackageName]" and then access it by putting "using [Namespace];" in my code. However, this doesn't seem to be working with the CarsonDB library. What am I doing wrong?

1. In Powershell 7 create a new empty directory and enter it.
2. Run "dotnet new winforms"
3. Run "dotnet add package CarsonDB"
4. Add "using CarsonDB;" to the top of Project.cs
5. Run "dotnet build"
6. Get the error: "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CarsonDB' could not be found..."

I expected the project to build with 0 errors.

Comment: Some info would be needed. Do you get any errors? What framework version is your project? Check the [CarsonDB nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CarsonDB#supportedframeworks-body-tab) documentation.

Comment: Not sure this is the reason, but CarsonDB's latest Version (1.1.2) is targeting .NET 4.5.2, which is very old. There might be nuget compatibility problems when referencing such old stuff (besides that I wouldn't use a library that is not yet .NET5.0+ compliant with any new development)

Comment: @PMF that is why I asked about that info. Usually `dotnet new` is used with templates that use faiirly recent frameworks, and CarsonDB looks like a kinda old package compatibility wise.